# Take a camera picture and send it to php server in iPhone

Tags: php, ios, web-services

I am working on gallery kind of iphone application. According to my requirement i need to send camera captured image to server using php url. I am storing captured image in application resource document directory.

here is my Php code -

```
$file_path = "../Gallery/";

   $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['Documents']['name']);
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Documents']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
       echo "Image is upload";
   } else{
       echo "Image is not Upload";
   }
```

here is my iPhone code -

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    CGFloat compression = 0.5f;

    UIImage *smallSizeImage = [self scaleImage:image toSize:CGSizeMake(140.0, 80.0)];
    imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(smallSizeImage, compression);

    ivPicture.image = smallSizeImage;

    self.passingNbPosition.positionImageId = [Util getNewGUID];

    [imageData writeToFile:[Util getFilePathForFileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg",self.passingNbPosition.positionImageId]] atomically:YES];


   // setting up the URL to post to
    NSString *urlString = @"http://...........php";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

     NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    /*
     now lets create the body of the post
     */
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.jpg\"\r\n", self.passingNbPosition.positionImageId] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(returnString);

}
```

Using above code after printing in console , i am getting return data but return string is coming "Image is not Upload". I dont know where is my mistake. I think it's an issue in my iPhone code. Can someone help me where i am doing wrong here.

Thanks..

Comment: Did you hear about `AFNetworking`? Try this third party library to hit url `https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking`

Comment: Thanks but i want to know where is my mistake in my above code ?

Comment: @KumarKlYes mate..i am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void) saveImageInServer
{
    /*
     turning the image into a NSData object
     getting the image back out of the UIImageView
     setting the quality to 90
     */
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.profilePicture.image, 90);
        // setting up the URL to post to
        NSString *urlString = @"http://webservices/image-upload.php";

        // setting up the request object now
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        /*
         add some header info now
         we always need a boundary when we post a file
         also we need to set the content type

         You might want to generate a random boundary.. this is just the same
         as my output from wireshark on a valid html post
         */
        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------147378098314876653456641449";
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        /*
         now lets create the body of the post
         */
        NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\%@.jpg\r\n",self.emailTextField.text];
        [body appendData: [stringData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        // setting the body of the post to the reqeust
        [request setHTTPBody:body];


        // now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);


}
```

This is the code within the application, as i told you, check your Gallery folder in your server, if it exists and you are pointing to it, it will work

Comment: @AliThanks for ur answer...I have printed some variables in console. Pls check it     (lldb) po stringData
$0 = 0x0818dd50 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userfile"; filename=9514172E-CF45-45CD-A490-E63613F48DCD.jpg

(lldb) po returnData
$1 = 0x073b5e30 <496d6167 65206973 206e6f74 2055706c 6f6164>
(lldb) po returnString
$2 = 0x076cb8b0 Image is not Upload

Comment: I dont know where i need to set our folder name "Documents" in body...is there any need to set folder name in below code ...      NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\%@.jpg\r\n",self.passingNbPosition.positionImageId];

Comment: Have you access to your webservice ?

Comment: <?php
$uploaddir = './images';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "http:/myserver/webservices/{$file}";
}
?>

Comment: Yeah Sure... once it will work i will give u 20 upvote my bro.

Comment: Thankuuuu @Ali. u are really very nice guy.. 25 upvote for u . :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send Images in multipart/form-data we have a third party API which is ASIHttpRequest.Go through the below link then you came to know how to use it.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Comment: Thanks for ur answer but i want to know where is my mistake in my above code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any errors in your code, may be some suggestion to fix this issue:

1. Put picking and uploading image in different methods
2. Check on your server if you really have a folder named Gallery in the right path, otherwise it won't work (try to create one by your own, and write the absolute path to it)

Comment: @AliCan u tell me an api what i am using here in my code. is it wrong or correct api ?